# Cannot build docker container (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core solution, that contains 3 projects.

I want to deploy it to the docker container.

Here is how the solution looks like[image]

Here is tree of solution

```
  TooSeeWeb
 |- aspnet-core(folder)
    |-TooSeeWeb (folder)
      |- TooSeeWeb.sln
      |-Dockerfile
      |- TooSeeWeb
         |- TooSeeWeb.csproj
      |- TooSeeWeb.Core(folder)
         |- TooSeeWeb.Core.csproj
      |- TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure(folder)
         |- TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.csproj
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln ./
COPY TooSeeWeb/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb/
COPY TooSeeWeb.Core/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Core/
COPY TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/.*csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app/TooSeeWeb
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "tooseeweb.dll"]
```

My problem, that when I try to do `docker build - < Dockerfile`

I got this error

> Step 3/13 : COPY *.sln ./
>   COPY failed: no source files were specified

How I can fix this?

Comment: from where you start the build command ? maybe you should copy using TooSeeWeb/*.sln ?

Comment: from folder where `.sln` file is @LinPy

Comment: the error indicate that *.sln return nothing, you need to double check that

Comment: tried your approach, same stuff @LinPy

Comment: I double-check it. with `ls` command in terminal. I see my `.sln` file @LinPy

Comment: do you have a .dockerignore file ?

Comment: yes, I have it
Here is what it's contains
`.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
*/bin
*/obj
**/.toolstarget`

 @LinPy

Comment: So I guess it must work, but for some reason, it not see `.sln` @LinPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `docker build - < Dockerfile`, the local current directory isn't the directory you're running the command from.

You can see what the local directory is if you say `COPY TooSeeWeb.sln ./` rather than `*.sln`. Then the error message will be something like `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder87634958792798/TooSeeWeb.sln: no such file or directory`.

If you instead use `docker build .` the local directory will be the directory you run the command from and your COPY command should work as expected.